# How to use JSON Engine with Android

Tags: java, android, json, google-app-engine

So I am trying to make Battleship for Android. I have an application set up on Google's App Engine. But that's as far as my understanding goes. I have been looking at countless tutorials and I'm completely confused.

I am coding in Java and would like a JSON Engine database to create documents, one JSON document for each game. I would need two players to be able to read and write onto that document and only two players (which would have their own unique ID). Is there a way to restrict it from other users? Also, once the game is over I would like to delete the document.

Could you give me some pointers on where to start? How to make sure that my app is connected to the right App Engine, and able to POST and GET from the datastore.

Thank you so much for any and all advice.

Here is a link to the GitHub of the project:
https://github.com/CGTheLegend/CMPS121_Spring2014_FinalProject

These are the links that I was looking at and would like to try to implement into my project:

https://code.google.com/p/jsonengine/

https://code.google.com/p/jsonengine/wiki/HowToUse

https://code.google.com/p/jsonengine/wiki/HowToUseQuery

Comment: Can you make this question more specific? This is super general...

Comment: I've also taken a look at Google's Cloud Endpoints, though the set up looks a lot easier I'm not sure if it will be able to accomplish what I need it to do. I would also love some advice on that.

Comment: I'm asking for advice on how to implement these technologies and how to go about implementation.

Answer (score 1):

To use JSON I would recommend Google's JSON library. Very easy to use and quite powerful.

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

And for my last project I've been using a pretty handy class to send JSON data through HTTP requests...

You can check the code for it @ my Github for it [here](https://github.com/fnk0/InsuringMyLife/blob/Master/InsuringMyLife/src/main/java/com/gabilheri/insuringmylife/JSONParser.java)

Just copy that class to your project and it's done you can use that JSONParser class using the makeHttpRequest method.

EDIT: 
[Here](http://pastebin.com/R3L15K8u) is a example on how to use the JSONParser class.

Edit: 
here is what you can do.

In your button you add:

```
android:onClick="getJSON"
```

and Them inside your Main Activity:

```
public void getJSON(View view) {
    // DO whatever you want with your onCLick.
    // If your method call to the JSON is in another class you can do the call from here
    // Example
    myOtherClass.getJSON();
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that I would get the JSON Object with makeHttpRequest() correct? Can I also POST using this function? And do I just put in the URL into the params of this function?

Comment: I also don't understand what the empty constructor is for?

Comment: Could I just use the makeHttpRequest from my main? Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: No. with that class you need to make the request from an AsyncTask or a thread that is not running on the UI Thread. 

To understand how to use it you can browse that project on github and you will see some classes with an inner AsyncTask using the methods. @GCTheLegend - I have a empty constructor just because I wanted to.

Comment: What does the JSONSender.java do?

Comment: Nothing. I was going to make a class to handle it usimg async and more rehusable but i ran out of time. I did that app for a contest so i realizee i wouldnt need that much calls to have to write a generic asynctask that did the requests for me easily. Using inner async tasks was faster :)

Comment: What do you mean by inner async tasks? I'm confused on how to use your function. Do I just have to run a separate thread that extends AsyncTask and call the function?

Comment: I'm at work right now. I'll give you a better example in a few hours :)

Comment: I updated my answer with an example on how you would call that from a activity.

Comment: What is <NameValuePair> ? Is it an ADT of that you created somewhere?

Comment: It is ab vuilt in adt class :)

Comment: So I implemented your files the same way that you showed in the example but it crashes. Should it be done onCreate? Right now I have it executing on a onClick function.

Comment: No, it can be executed in an onClick() function. I have it done in a several apps that way. Can you post your logcat info? Did you added permission Internet in the manifest?

Comment: I do have Internet permission.

Comment: 06-07 12:54:57.547: E/AndroidRuntime(492): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-07 12:54:57.547: E/AndroidRuntime(492): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method getJSON(View) in the activity class com.example.battleship.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'getButton'

Comment: getJson is in another activity and is associated with the getButton. I though it would have been an issue with getButton being referenced somewhere to something else in my R.java. But I tried deleting it, updating the name of the button using the GUI and updating the references and even changing it back to the original name, but no dice.

Comment: To what I see there is that your code is not finding the method call. Did you tried using log it to the console to see if you are registering the button call? 

If your button is calling the method getJSON you should have a method inside your MainActivity called getJSON(View view)

Comment: But I'm using the button in another activity for testing. I also have the getJSON(View v) method in the corresponding .java file. That should work right?

Comment: Well.... You should take a look at your code them or post it here. Because your logcat is complaining that inside your MainActivity there is no method `public void getJSON(View view) {}`